# How should one cast a proxy as an entity in a Spring Controller?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-data

A REST service in a Spring Boot app is being called from an AngularJS app, but the Spring Controller is not able to perform a simple find query on the data source.  Instead, the following error is thrown:

```
java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access class demo.WebLead from class com.sun.proxy.$Proxy111
```

**What specific changes need to be made to the code below in order for the REST service to be able to perform the query without throwing this error?**

The line of code that throws the error in the Spring controller is:

```
WebLead wld = myrepo.findByIdlead(idl);
```

The same error is thrown also when the preceding line of code is altered to explicitly cast the returned entity as follows:

```
WebLead wld = (WebLead)myrepo.findByIdlead(idl);
```

The relevant parts of the Spring Boot controller and app in `UiApplication.java` are:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@Controller
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "demo", considerNestedRepositories = true)
public class UiApplication extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private WebLeadRepository myrepo;// {}

    @RequestMapping(value = "/some-url", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody ResultMessage submitPhone(HttpSession session, @RequestBody ResultPhone rphon) {
            ResultMessage resmess = new ResultMessage("phonetest");
        try{
            Long idl = Long.parseLong(rphon.getWleadid());
            WebLead wld = (WebLead)myrepo.findByIdlead(idl);
            return resmess;
        } catch(Exception e){return resmess;}
    } 

    //other stuff
}
```

`WebLeadRepository.java` is:

```
public interface WebLeadRepository extends JpaRepository<WebLead, Long> {

    WebLead findByIdlead(Long idl);
}
```

`WebLead.java` is:

```
@Entity
class WebLead {

    @GeneratedValue
    @Id
    private Long idlead;
    private String firstname;
    private String lastname;
    private String emailaddress;
    @Column(name="creation_date")
    private DateTime creationdate;

    public Long getIdlead(){return this.idlead;}

    public String getFirstname(){return firstname;}
    public void setFirstname(String fn){this.firstname = fn;}

    public String getLastname(){return lastname;}
    public void setLastname(String ln){this.lastname = ln;}

    public String getEmailaddress(){return emailaddress;}
    public void setEmailaddress(String em){this.emailaddress = em;}

    public DateTime getCreationdate(){return creationdate;}
    public void setCreationdate(DateTime ad){creationdate=ad;}

}
```

The complete stack trace is:

```
2016-01-07 19:14:39.780 ERROR 21606 --- [nio-9000-exec-4] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access class demo.WebLead from class com.sun.proxy.$Proxy111] with root cause

java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access class demo.WebLead from class com.sun.proxy.$Proxy111
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy111.findByIdlead(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at demo.UiApplication.submitPhone(UiApplication.java:244) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:222) ~[spring-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137) ~[spring-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:814) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:737) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.EndpointWebMvcAutoConfiguration$ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.doFilterInternal(EndpointWebMvcAutoConfiguration.java:242) ~[spring-boot-actuator-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.trace.WebRequestTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(WebRequestTraceFilter.java:111) ~[spring-boot-actuator-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:316) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:126) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:90) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:122) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:169) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:48) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:158) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:120) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at demo.UiApplication$SecurityConfiguration$1.doFilterInternal(UiApplication.java:399) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:120) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:64) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:91) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:53) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:213) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:176) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346) ~[spring-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262) ~[spring-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:87) ~[spring-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77) ~[spring-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:121) ~[spring-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(MetricsFilter.java:103) ~[spring-boot-actuator-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:217) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:673) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_45]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_45]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `WebLead` class is package-local (because you omitted any acccess level modifier). But Spring Data creates a proxy for the repository interface, and that proxy (com.sun.proxy...) is in another package, so it cannot acccess your entity class. Change the modifier of `WebLead` to `public`, then it should work.

Comment: That did it.  Thank you and +1.

Comment: But shouldnt the modifier be protected instead of public? I am on my phone now and unable to test it on my devbox.

Comment: No, `protected` will likely also fail, since the proxy of the repository and your entity are neither in the same package nor in the same type hierarchy.